# Is it possible to modify the code of a predefined learner in mlr3?

Tags: r, mlr3

I'm interested in locally removing these two dependencies in the `"regr.svm"` learner code:

[Dependency 1: Cost](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3learners/blob/e7d53f5a666fdaea93e8bfd20aab6b994bdb6bd3/R/LearnerRegrSVM.R#L41)

[Dependency 2: Epsilon](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3learners/blob/e7d53f5a666fdaea93e8bfd20aab6b994bdb6bd3/R/LearnerRegrSVM.R#L46)

I have tried without success with the `trace()` function:

```r
trace(LearnerRegrSVM.R, edit = TRUE)
```

I opened a [related issue](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3learners/issues/208) on Gitgub a few days ago, but I have not received a response.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{mlr3} learners are wrappers around the original implementations and are not editable by the user.

If something is wrong, you are always welcome to submit a PR in the respective GitHub repo and we'll have a look.

IF you want to modify code quickly, you can always fork the repo, make adjustments yourself and use your own fork.

(Asking on Stackoverflow should usually include some code, otherwise people will flag to close the question.)